# Create a Custom Button Grid with JqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I understand the title of my question may suggest that it has been asked before but I think my question is different enough and warrants asking since I couldn't find any resource on how to do this.

I would like to create an entire grid like table consisting of buttons in the image I have attached  [Grid of Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRjnO.png)

Is this possible using JqGrid??

Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0):

i did custom button grid before in each column in row data by send raw html tag in json data to bind in Grid. is that what you want?

```
 var json = [
               {col1:"<button>test1</button>", col2:"<button>test2</button>"},
               {col1:"<button>test3</button>", col2:"<button>test4</button>"},
               {col1:"<button>test5</button>", col2:"<button>test6</button>"}
            ] ;
```